# How to save custom form control input data in web part?

Tags: kentico, form-control

I followed the "Developing Custom Form Control" in kentico documentation and built a custom list box. I added the list box dynamically on the code behind and NOT adding it directly on the code front (ascx). I use the list box on one of my web parts and everything works well when I selected multiple items. However, when I click to edit the web part, all of the selected items are gone and the the list box comes back to its original form ( no item selected ). Therefore, I wonder how kentico save the old data of the form control in the web part.

On the code below, I recreate my scenario with a short version. I dynamically add the list box under a panel.

```
protected void EnsureItems()
  {
      // Create item and list box
      ListBox tab = new ListBox(); 

      ListItem item = new ListItem();
      item.Text = "test";

      tab.Items.Add(item);
      panel.Controls.Add(tab);
  }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      EnsureItems();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Form Control should be inherited from **FormEngineUserControl**. And Kentico utilizes **Value** property then to store and retrieve values from the db. Here is the example:

```
public override object Value
{
    get
    {
        return listBox.SelectedValue;
    }

    set
    {
        listBox.SelectedValue = ValidationHelper.GetString(value, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Basically, your getter should return some value to be stored in the database. And in the setter you should initialize your listbox, fill with data and make a selection base on **value** coming from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a form control itself doesn't save data to the database.  The form control is attached to some form and the form saves the data to the database. Check out the [documentation regarding custom form controls](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/developing-form-controls).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just knew that the setter of the Value method is actually pulled from the database which I used to retrieve the old data